# Setting a "build directory" in vim?

Tags: vim, ide, build

Is there a way to tell vim to run the `makeprg` in a specific directory? I use per-project .vimrc files, and they would seem the perfect place to inform vim of where each project should be built, regardless of the current directory.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
 :let &makeprg='(cd /tmp && make)'
```

seems to work nicely for me

```
 :se makepgr="(cd %:h/.. && make)"
```

to make it go to the parent directory

#### Note

The above worked on windows when I tried it; Today on linux I found out that I somehow had to use the following incantations to get the same to work:

```
:let &makeprg='(cd %:h/.. && make)'
```

> **Note** I'm assuming you don't actually use make, because that would be a simple `:make -C /tmp` away
>
> **Note** most other automated build systems have a similar option, e.g. `:!scons -C /tmp`

Comment: Another useful technique is to create a script called make_wrapper or something that looks at an environment var such as MY_BUILD_DIR and simply does a: make -C $MY_BUILD_DIR $@ if it is set otherwise normal make.  Then in vim have makeprg set to the script instead of make.  Then you can get the same behavior outside of vim as well.

Comment: @Neg_EV: perhaps just `:let &mp='make -C $MY_BUILD_DIR'` and be done

Comment: @sehe I wanted it to work even when MY_BUILD_DIR wasn't set.  Which you could also do in one line but I also do this stuff from the command line.  So having a script that i could alias make=make_wrapper to was useful so I only had the solution in one place.

Comment: @sehe Also if you want to still be able to use -C or --directory you can easily add that argument checking into the script.